# Incremental write

Tags: export, save

If I have two loop `i & j`, and I need record time and value of `i, j` incrementally  during each round, how to modify the following code. THANKS!

```
For[i=1,i<5,i++,
  For[j=1,j<5,j++,
    Export["Result.txt",StringJoin[DateString[TimeObject[]], " ", ToString[i], ToString[j]]];
  ]]
```

Comment: Either create a `Table` and export at once or use `OpenWrite/Write`.

Comment: Hahahaha, great~